# Concurreny modelin grpc server in golang

Tags: go, concurrency, grpc, grpc-go

I have created a sample gRPC client and server in golang (used protobufs). I understand the concurrency model in golang. However, I am trying to understand the concurrency model in a server accepting parallel requests from same client(multiple goroutines on client side)/ multiple clients.

More specifically:

1. When a new gRPC call comes, does server create a new goroutine?
2. What data is shared by these goroutines? Does `grpcServer.Serve` set the boundary for data shared across goroutines i.e. everything set before is shared? (I am thinking of threads in Java where the threads share global data)

Answer (score 1):

> When a new gRPC call comes, does server create a new goroutine?

Yes, and it's highly likely that it creates a lot of concurrent goroutines to handle every connection and request (especially streaming request).

> What data is shared by these goroutines?

I think this question is too broad. There are too much code both in `net/http2` and `google.golang.org/grpc` packages to answer your question without deep investigation. However, we can be sure, that these goroutines share at least the server itself, because [`ServeConn`](https://github.com/golang/net/blob/release-branch.go1.12/http2/server.go#L316) is not a free function, but a method defined on `http2.Server` type.